# String template not displayed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a problem with creating components/templates. I'm practically following the instructions here:

https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/components

My code is basically the same as the one in the video ( except the error of course)

My Problem is, that the component doesn't get displayed at all.

Here is my complete Vue.JS code:

```
Vue.config.devtools = true;
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#app',

});
Vue.component('product', {
    template:
    `<div class='product'>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Items [[ cart ]]</button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">
                <img :src=image class="rounded float-left" alt="..." style="width: 50%">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md">
                <h1>Products: [[ title ]]</h1>
                <p>Description: [[ description ]]</p>
                <p v-if="inStock">In Stock</p>
                <p v-else :class="{outOfStock: inStock == 0}">Out of stock</p>
                <ul v-for="detail in details">
                    <li>[[ detail ]]</li>
                </ul>
                <div v-for="(variant, index) in variants"
                     :key="variant.variantId"
                     class="color-box"
                     @mouseover="updateProduct(variant.variantImage, index)"
                     :style="{ backgroundColor: variant.variantColor }">
                </div>
                <br>
                <button @click="addToCart"
                        :disabled="!inStock">
                    Add to Cart
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            product: 'Essen ',
            brand: "Muhannad Kalieh",
            description: 'Thats my description for the socks',
            selectedVariant: 0,
            onSale: true,
            details: ["Selber zubereitet", "frische Zutaten", "schmeckt geil nahuj"],
            variants: [
                {
                    variantId: 2224,
                    variantColor: "green",
                    variantQuantity: 15,
                    variantImage: '/images/essen1.jpeg',
                    sale: 1
                },
                {
                    variantId: 34,
                    variantColor: "blue",
                    variantQuantity: 0,
                    variantImage: '/images/essen2.jpeg',
                    sale: 0
                }
            ],
            cart: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart() {
            this.cart += 1
        },
        updateProduct(variantImage, index) {
            this.selectedVariant = index;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        title() {
            return this.brand + ' ' + this.product;
        },
        image() {
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantImage;
        },
        inStock() {
            return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantQuantity;
        }
    }
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <product></product>
</div>
```

before I tried to use my code as a component, all the code worked. Maybe its because the delimeters? or the backticks `` ? I really don't have any clue anymore

Thanks for any help!

Comment: // Edit -- I changed the delimeters do [[ var ]] because I'm using vue.js with the laravel framework. And Laravels delimeters are with {{ }}

Comment: try to add `<div>` before `<div class='product'>`

Comment: tried that, haven't worked for me

Comment: what's the extension of this file? .vue?

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: no the file is a .js -- but the vue js code works fine. Everything was working besides vue.component

Comment: no I don't use webpack

Comment: what error do you get in the console of your browser?

Comment: Unknown custom element: <product> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: Try to put your `Vue.component` above the `var app = new Vue({`

Comment: haven't worked, sorry :/

Comment: Did you remove the `<div>` before `<div class='product'>`? Put `<div>` before your `<div class="product">` because I tried a simple test here. it's working on me

Comment: hey! The vue.component above var.app worked !! I tried that again because there was a little typing-error !!! Thanks mate, I was trying to figure out this for 2 days! Write a answer and I will mark it as true :)

Comment: Oh glad to know that. Sure buddy, so we can help other readers as well. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare your component above your vue instance. In Vue.js template, you need to envelope your custom template inside the additional `<div></div>` It will like this:

```
// your template
Vue.component('product', {
template:
    `
     <div>
         <div class='product'>
           ... your vue codes here
         </div>
     </div>
    `    
});

Vue.config.devtools = true;
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: whoops I was a little late :-) didnt follow your comments

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the component before you instantiate the new Vue instance.
Further, for the delimiters to work, you need to put them in the component declaration.

You can see a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zvk49nm0j)

```
Vue.component('product', {
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  template:....
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```